# Ugly edge insertion with thick oblique line

Tags: tikz-pgf

With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle] (a) at (0,0) {$A$};
\node[draw,circle] (b) at (1,1) {$B$};
\draw[line width=3pt] (a.north) to (b.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I obtain the following image:

[image]

Is there a way to have a nice insertion of the thick edge in the nodes?

Comment: What do you mean a nice insertion? Do you want the line behind the circles?

Comment: Yes, and that it doesn't interrupt before the node (in the outer parts)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

- Fill the circles with white,
- Use layers to put the thick line in the `background` and
- Shift the two end points vertically:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%% -------------------------------------- Declare the layers
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
        \node[draw,circle,red,  fill=white] (a) at (0,0) {$A$};
        \node[draw,circle,blue, fill=white] (b) at (1,1) {$B$};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    % -----------------------
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \draw[line width=3pt] 
                ([yshift=-0.30ex]a.north) to ([yshift=+0.30ex]b.south);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That might work, but this would require to manually modify several images in which I use thick edges. I was thinking of a solution that applies to the edge's style, avoiding this problem.